# Visualforce Public Form DoS Security

Tags: visualforce, security, force.com-sites

I have created a public registration form for clients. No login/credentials are required to submit the form. It is reachable via a custom url of this format: `my-custom-subdomain.force.com`. It is built with Visualforce. The form creates custom object records. It's not a "Web-to-Lead" form.

The form has not yet been deployed into production. I am asking this question preemptively.

I would like to please know:

How can I defend against DoS attacks? Scenario: a DoS attack could exhaust my [SF Sites page views quota](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.sites_limits.htm&type=5). Apparently, [it's happened to people](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000D8rwIAC).

This is my first time asking a question on [salesforce.stackexchange.com](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Have you considered using CAPTCHA . " Completely Automated Public Turing test to tell Computers and Humans Apart".

Comment: @ClintD'Silva AFAIK CAPTCHA solves a different problem: spam form submissions. If I visit a CAPTCHA-protected page without even trying to submit the form, then it will count against the page view quota.